# vba Word - statusbar is flickering due to calculations

Tags: vba, ms-word, statusbar, flicker

I want to use the statusbar for update Information during long calculations in Word. However, the statusbar flickers and switches back to the "normal" statusbar during calculations.

Example:

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    Dim dummy As Double
    
    For i = 1 To 100
        Application.StatusBar = "Please be patient... i=" & i
        ' waiting loop: Flickering due to calculations
        For j = 1 To 90000
            dummy = Sqr(j) ^ 3
            dummy = Sqr(dummy)
        Next
        ' just waiting: (almost) No flickering
        'CreateObject("Excel.Application").Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Next
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

If you change the *waiting loop* with the commended *CreateObject...*, the flickering is almost gone. I tried also *Application.ScreenUpdating* but it doesn't work.

How can I stop the flickering during the calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status bar is flickering because you’ve including its updating in the loop. In effect, it repaints itself on each iteration.

Move it out of the loop and then obviously don’t include the variable “i”.

Another workaround is to put a condition in the loop that checks the counter and only repaints the status bar at 25% done, 50% done and 75% done time frames.

Comment: The statusbar flickers because it always shows the "normal" statusbar in between, e.g. Number of words. The status must be updated in the loop. Otherwise, the update does not make sense for long-running calculations.

Comment: @musbach and that is why I made the suggestion to limit the number of times you update the status bar message. In stead of on every iteration, maybe update it only 4 to 6 times during the process.